# using AWK how to remove these kind of Duplicates?

Tags: awk

I am new to AWK, I have some basic ideas in AWK. I want to remove duplicates in a file,
for example:

```
    0008.ASIA. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    0008.ASIA. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    ns1.0008.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    www.0008.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    anish.asia NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    ns2.anish.asia NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN
    ANISH.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
```

This is a sample file, from that using this command I got the output like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/^[^ ]+asia/ { gsub(/\.$/,"",$1);split($1,a,".")} length(a)==2{b[$1]++;}END{for (x in b)print x}'
```

> 0008.ASIA.
>     anish.asia.
>     ANISH.asia

But I want output like this

```
  008.ASIA
  anish.asia
```

or

```
008.ASIA
ANISH.asia
```

How do I remove these kind of duplicates?

Thanks in Advance 
Anish kumar.V

Thanks for your immediate reponse, Actually I wrote a complete script in bash, now I am in final stage. How to invoke python in that :-(

```
#!/bin/bash

current_date=`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S`
today=`date +%d%m%Y`
yesterday=`date -d 'yesterday' '+%d%m%Y'`
RootPath=/var/domaincount/asia/
MainPath=$RootPath${today}asia
LOG=/var/tmp/log/asia/asiacount$current_date.log

mkdir -p $MainPath
echo Intelliscan Process started for Asia TLD $current_date 

exec 6>&1 >> $LOG

#################################################################################################
## Using Wget Downloading the Zone files it will try only one time
if ! wget --tries=1 --ftp-user=USERNAME --ftp-password=PASSWORD ftp://ftp.anish.com:21/zonefile/anish.zone.gz
then
    echo Download Not Success Domain count Failed With Error
    exit 1
fi
###The downloaded file in Gunzip format from that we need to unzip and start the domain count process####
gunzip asia.zone.gz > $MainPath/$today.asia

###### It will start the Count #####
awk '/^[^ ]+ASIA/ && !_[$1]++{print $1; tot++}END{print "Total",tot,"Domains"}' $MainPath/$today.asia > $RootPath/zonefile/$today.asia
awk '/Total/ {print $2}' $RootPath/zonefile/$today.asia > $RootPath/$today.count

a=$(< $RootPath/$today.count)
b=$(< $RootPath/$yesterday.count)
c=$(awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{tot++}END{print tot}' $RootPath/zonefile/$today.asia $RootPath/zonefile/$yesterday.asia)

echo "$current_date Count For Asia TlD $a"
echo "$current_date Overall Count For Asia TlD $c"
echo "$current_date New Registration Domain Counts $((c - a))"
echo "$current_date Deleted Domain Counts $((c - b))"

exec >&6 6>&-
cat $LOG | mail -s "Asia Tld Count log" 07anis@gmail.com
```

In that

```
 awk '/^[^ ]+ASIA/ && !_[$1]++{print $1; tot++}END{print "Total",tot,"Domains"}' $MainPath/$today.asia > $RootPath/zonefile/$today.asia
```

in this part only now I am searching how to get the distinct values so any suggestions using AWK is better for me. Thanks again for your immediate response.

Comment: Sorry, but add having your whole Bash script posted here doesn't really make things clearer. Can you reduce your question to a small example plus a statement of the problem you're currently facing?

Comment: Hi now Problem is my firs post alone, i just shown here i wrote a script...is there any possibility using AWK itself and i don't have much idea in python..

Comment: Can you clean up your question? It would really help a lot.

Comment: Hi Dude, sorry my English is not good compare to you,

Comment: and my problem is currently instead of your python code any other option using AWK itself, because i wrote my entire script..now if i move python means it take too much of time for me...

Comment: :) Don't worry, your English is fine. It's OK to continue using AWK, because your script probably just needs a few improvements. Can you [edit] your question to make it shorter and simpler? That way, we will know what you need help with.

Answer (score 2):

```
kent$  cat a
0008.ASIA. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
0008.ASIA. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
ns1.0008.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
www.0008.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
anish.asia NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
ns2.anish.asia NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN
ANISH.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.


kent$  awk -F' NS' '{ gsub(/\.$/,"",$1);split($1,a,".")} length(a)==2{b[tolower($1)]++;}END{for (x in b)print x}' a
anish.asia
0008.asia
```

btw, it is interesting, that I gave you a solution at http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/167512-using-awk-how-its-possible.html, and you add something new in your file, then I added the `tolower()` function here.   :D

Answer (score 1):

By putting your AWK script into a separate file, you can tell what's really going on. Here's a simple approach to your "filter out the duplicates" problem:

```
# For each line in the file
{

  # Decide on a unique key (eg. case insensitive without trailing period)
  unique_key = tolower($1)
  sub(/\.$/, "", unique_key)

  # If this line isn't a duplicate (it hasn't been found yet)
  if (!(unique_key in already_found)) {

    # Mark this unique key as found
    already_found[unique_key] = "found"

    # Print out the relevant data
    print($1)
  }
}
```

You can run AWK files by passing the [`-f` option](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#Options) to `awk`.

If the above script isn't recognizable as an AWK script, here it is in inline form:

```
awk '{ key = tolower($1); sub(/\.$/, "", key); if (!(key in found)) { found[key] = 1; print($1) } }'
```

Comment: Kindly look again my question itself, because of low reputation i edited my question itself...

Comment: Thanks alot man but it not get the uniq dataa

0008.ASIA
ns1.0008.asia
www.0008.asia
anish.asia
ns2.anish.asia

But i want the output only main domains. only

0008.ASIA
anish.asia

Comment: I will not write the whole script for you. Try to modify what Kent or I has answered with. Then [edit] your question if you're still stuck. If you need to learn more AWK, read the [Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Awk_Primer).

Answer (score 1):

Or, just use the shell:

```
echo '    0008.ASIA. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    0008.ASIA. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    ns1.0008.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    www.0008.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    anish.asia NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
    ns2.anish.asia NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN
    ANISH.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.' |
while read domain rest; do
    domain=${domain%.}
    case "$domain" in
        (*.*.*) : ;;
        (*.[aA][sS][iI][aA]) echo "$domain" ;;
    esac
done |
sort -fu
```

produces

```
0008.ASIA
anish.asia
```

Comment: His sample output indicates he has stripped sub-domains like ns1, ns2. +1 for Nice use of bash `while read ... case ...` pipline!

Comment: Indeed. Updated to exclude domains with 2 (or more) dots.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use AWK.  Use Python

```
import readlines
result= set()
for line in readlines:
    words = lines.split()
    if "asia" in words[0].lower():
        result.add( words[0].lower() )
for name in result:
    print name
```

That might be easier to work with than AWK.  Yes.  It's longer.  But it may be easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reponse, Actually i wrote a complete script in bash, now iam in final stage..how to invoke python in that :-(

Comment: "how to invoke python"?  What?  It's just like AWK:  `python yourscript.py`.   Also.  That question has already been asked.  And that question is trivially answered via `man python` at the command prompt.  And that question is trivially answered by reading documentation at http://www.python.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution. Let `sort` create your cased-folded and uniq list (and it will be sorted!)

```
  {
   cat - <<EOS
   0008.ASIA. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
   0008.ASIA. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
   ns1.0008.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
   www.0008.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
   anish.asia NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.
   ns2.anish.asia NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN
   ANISH.asia. NS AS2.DNS.ASIA.CN.

EOS
 } |   awk '{
      #dbg print "$0=" $0
      targ=$1
      sub(/\.$/, "", targ)
      n=split(targ,tmpArr,".")
      #dbg print "n="n
      if (n > 2) targ=tmpArr[n-1] "." tmpArr[n]
      print targ 
     }' \
 | sort -f -u
```

**output**

```
0008.ASIA
anish.asia
```

Edit: fixed `sort -i -u` to `sort -f -u`. Many other unix utilties use '-i' to indcate 'ignorecase'. My test showed me I need to fix it, and I forgot to fix the final posting.